# How to align index columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indexing

I followed the example posted by @Schweinebacke [Customizing Index - Adding chapter heading and verse number to index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31237/customizing-index-adding-chapter-heading-and-verse-number-to-index-entries)  and it works great. However I would like to change the appeareance of index. To show the change I am attaching an image with this mail.

I would like to align the columns of index, first column left justified, right column right justified and middle column left justified.

I would really appreciate your help
[image]

Comment: any expectation/restrictions on the size of the material in each "column", e.g., can one assume that everything is always fitting onto a single line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only going to offer you an outline of the solution, you should then customize it according to your taste.

Basic approach is to provide a style file for makeindex so that you effectively get an `.ind` file containing a `longtable` environment. The parts of an index line then have to be separated not by comma but by `&` and the lines should end in `\\`.

The `&` between "verse" and "chapter" would be generated by the index command itself, e.g. from the other question:

```
\newcommand*{\vindex}[2]{%
  \setcounter{verse}{#2}%
  \sindex[vrs]{#1& \currentchapter}%     % <---
}
```

And we also need to load the packages we use later:

```
\usepackage{longtable,array}
```

The rest is done by the special style for makeindex (that should be saved in a file, say `verse.ist`:

```
preamble "\\section*{\\indexname}
\\newcommand\\ignoreNL[1]{}          % throw away \\ after new group
\\setlength\\LTleft{0pt}
\\setlength\\LTright{0pt}
\\begin{longtable}{l!{\\extracolsep{\\fill}}lr}"
postamble "\\end{longtable}"

item_0 "\\\\\n"     % \\ between entries
delim_0 "&"         % &  between text and "page" number

group_skip "\n \\\\[5pt] \\ignoreNL"   % extra space 5pt between groups
```

#### Notes:

I used `\section*`for the heading, but with the book class you will probably want `\chapter*` and you may or may not want to add "running headers" and a TOC entry.

One problem with index style files is that there is no handle to add something after the page number only between entries (`item_0`). However, if there is a group change we may want to add extra space and if we do this then we would get `\\[5pt] \\` which isn't we want. So we additionally add `\ignoreNL` which simply gobbles the following `\\`.

#### Applying the index style file

I found it surprisingly difficult to make splitindex work with TeXworks, in fact I didn't manage if a style file was to be used. So in the end I used the commandline for that. Here is how this looks:

```
splitindex.exe -m "makeindex -s verse.ist" tmp
```

with "tmp.tex" being my test file. One more run of LaTeX and we get:

[image]

Comment: I tried to apply same concept to get `text` `chapter #` `Page numbers`. it worked great however I got all zeros for page numbers. All I wanted to change was verse numbers to page numbers.

Comment: Works great, however its consuming the entire page width, is there a way to keep the standard index format of two columns, that looks lot more like a book style. if required you can reduce the font size to put two columns per page, like the usual index output.