# How to integrate a tabular environment in the Index

Tags: tables, imakeidx, makeindex

In the index of my Japanese document, I want each entry to consist of:

1. The English name of the Japanese character (left-aligned)
2. The Japanese character itself (left-aligned)
3. The page number on which the associated entry can be found (right-aligned)

The information inside the parentheses above gives the horizontal alignment of each entry.

After fiddling with the code provided in this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45555/how-to-align-index-columns), I made some progress but stumbled into other problems:

- The index is not splitting over 4 columns as stipulated in the \makeindex command.
- There is a pagebreak between the index title and contents.

I'm not very fluent in constructing style files, and would really appreciate a solution accompanied with clear explanations (as far as possible).  I also find the bottom table in this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Indices#%2FParameters_for_the_.5Cmakeindex_command) a bit difficult to interpret.

In the code block below is my MWE.  For the sake of thoroughness, I included many index entries to test the robustness of my code.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{ltjbook}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage[left=1.9cm,right=1.9cm,bottom=1.5cm,top=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,longtable,supertabular,booktabs,multicol,multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{filecontents*}{general.ist}
headings_flag 5
heading_prefix "\n\\rmfamily\\textbf{"heading_suffix "} "
preamble "\\chapter*{\\indexname}%
\\newcommand\\ignoreNL[1]{}%
\\begin{tabular}{llr} "
postamble " \\end{tabular} "
item_0 "\\\\\n "
delim_0 "&"
delim_1 "\\hfill "
group_skip "\n \\\\[5pt] \\ignoreNL "
\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex[name=gen, title={Index of Kanji}, columns=4, columnseprule, options=-s general.ist]

\newcommand{\gindex}[2]{\index[gen]{#1 & #2}}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\gindex{One}{一}

\gindex{Two}{二}

\gindex{Three}{三}

\Blindtext
\gindex{Four}{四}

\gindex{Five}{五}

\gindex{Six}{六}

\gindex{Seven}{七}

\gindex{Eight}{八}

\gindex{Nine}{九}

\blindtext
\gindex{Ten}{十}

\gindex{Eleven}{十一}

\gindex{Twelve}{十二}

\gindex{Thirteen}{十三}

\gindex{Fourteen}{十四}

\gindex{Fifteen}{十五}

\gindex{Sixteen}{十六}

\gindex{Seventeen}{十七}

\gindex{Eighteen}{十八}

\gindex{Nineteen}{十九}

\gindex{Twenty}{二十}

\gindex{Mouth}{口}

\gindex{Neck}{首}

\gindex{Head}{頭}

\gindex{Lips}{唇}

\gindex{Arms}{腕}

\gindex{Feet}{足}

\gindex{Sunday}{日曜日}

\gindex{Monday}{月曜日}

\gindex{Tuesday}{火曜日}

\gindex{Wednesday}{水曜日}

\gindex{Thursday}{木曜日}

\gindex{Friday}{金曜日}

\gindex{Saturday}{土曜日}

\gindex{Wind}{風}

\gindex{Water}{水}

\gindex{Fire}{火}

\gindex{Flower}{花}

\blindtext
\gindex{East}{東}

\gindex{South}{南}

\gindex{North}{北}

\blindtext
\gindex{West}{西}


\printindex[gen]

\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing Index inserting unwanted pagebreak, and not splitting over multiple columns]

**>>EDIT:  29 January 2022<<**

After working with the entire document, the first page of the index is producing an anomaly as seen below.  Any help?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index is inside a `tabular`, which won't break across pages, and neither across columns. So you must use a breakable table, like `longtable`. To get a `longtable` inside `multicols` you must use a trick, like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46001/113546).

This brings me to this solution (for some reason I have to do the `multicols` myself; it seems `\makeindex` is not doing it.

**EDIT: I fiddled a bit with `general.ist` to prevent a column/page break between the group letter and the next entry.**

**EDIT 2:** I added a `\\makeatother` for safety.

**EDIT 2022/01/30** It appears that `longtable` ruins the internal LaTeX parameter `\@colroom`, which `multicols` needs to break the text into columns, at least when the text doesn't fit on the page. `\@colroom` is calculated right at the beginning of the `multicols` environment, before any text has been processed inside it. For following pages it is calculated again, so these are not affected. I solved this by saving `\@colroom` before the `longtable` and restoring it after. I also made some other minor improvements. I made `\tabcolsep` a bit smaller to better fit the index in the columns.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{ltjbook}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage[left=1.9cm,right=1.9cm,bottom=1.5cm,top=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,longtable,supertabular,booktabs,multicol,multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newlength\mysavecolroom
% This command inhibits a column break after a group letter in the index
% It also swallows the following \\, because the \\ is here before the \nopagebreak.
\newcommand{\dontbreak}[1]{\\\nopagebreak} % Swallow the following \\
\begin{filecontents*}{general.ist}
headings_flag 5
heading_prefix "\n\\rmfamily\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\dontbreak "
preamble "\\chapter*{\\indexname}%
\\newcommand\\ignoreNL[1]{}%
\\begin{multicols}{4}
\\makeatletter\\mysavecolroom=\\@colroom\\makeatother
\\setbox\\ltmcbox\\vbox{
\\makeatletter\\col@number\\@ne\\makeatother
\\setlength\\tabcolsep{4pt}
\\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}llr@{}}"
postamble "\n\\end{longtable}
\\unskip
\\unpenalty
\\unpenalty}
\\makeatletter\\@colroom=\\mysavecolroom\\makeatother
\\unvbox\\ltmcbox
\\end{multicols}
"
item_0 "\\\\\n "
delim_0 "&"
delim_1 "\\hfill "
group_skip "\n \\\\[5pt] \\ignoreNL "
\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex[name=gen, title={Index of Kanji}, columns=4, columnseprule, options=-s general.ist]

\newcommand{\gindex}[2]{\index[gen]{#1 & #2}}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\gindex{One}{一}

\gindex{Two}{二}

\gindex{Three}{三}

\Blindtext
\gindex{Four}{四}

\gindex{Five}{五}

\gindex{Six}{六}

\gindex{Seven}{七}

\gindex{Eight}{八}

\gindex{Nine}{九}

\blindtext
\gindex{Ten}{十}

\gindex{Eleven}{十一}

\gindex{Twelve}{十二}

\gindex{Thirteen}{十三}

\gindex{Fourteen}{十四}

\gindex{Fifteen}{十五}

\gindex{Sixteen}{十六}

\gindex{Seventeen}{十七}

\gindex{Eighteen}{十八}

\gindex{Nineteen}{十九}

\gindex{Twenty}{二十}

\gindex{Mouth}{口}

\gindex{Neck}{首}

\gindex{Head}{頭}

\gindex{Lips}{唇}

\gindex{Arms}{腕}

\gindex{Feet}{足}

\gindex{Sunday}{日曜日}

\gindex{Monday}{月曜日}

\gindex{Tuesday}{火曜日}

\gindex{Wednesday}{水曜日}

\gindex{Thursday}{木曜日}

\gindex{Friday}{金曜日}

\gindex{Saturday}{土曜日}

\gindex{Wind}{風}

\gindex{Water}{水}

\gindex{Fire}{火}

\gindex{Flower}{花}

\blindtext
\gindex{East}{東}

\gindex{South}{南}

\gindex{North}{北}

\blindtext
\gindex{West}{西}

  \printindex[gen]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 4 (Jan 31, 2022):**

Here is another solution for `general.ist` that I find cleaner. It doesn't need `\newlength\mysavecolroom`.

```
headings_flag 5
heading_prefix "\n\\rmfamily\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\dontbreak "
preamble "\\chapter*{\\indexname}%
\\newcommand\\ignoreNL[1]{}%
\\setbox\\ltmcbox\\vbox{
\\setlength\\tabcolsep{4pt}
% \\hsize=(\\linewidth-(n-1)\\columnsep)/n
% where n = number of columns
\\setlength{\\hsize}{\\dimexpr(\\linewidth-3\\columnsep)/4}
\\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}llr@{}}"
postamble "\\end{longtable}
\\unskip
\\unpenalty
\\unpenalty}
\\begin{multicols}{4}
\\unvbox\\ltmcbox
\\end{multicols}
"
item_0 "\\\\\n "
delim_0 "&"
delim_1 "\\hfill "
group_skip "\n \\\\[5pt] \\ignoreNL "
```

[image]

Comment: The output looks awesome.  Thank you very much!  @Pieter, if possible, may I ask you to edit your post and unpack the contents of the .ist file step by step.  I'd like to enhance my understanding on what the commands do/mean...  :-)

Comment: A last thought @Pieter van Oostrum, if you could help solve a related problem on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593382/categorising-and-aligning-entries-in-index) (see **Edit 1 on 2021/04/29**) it would be of great help!

Comment: **@Pieter van Oostrum**, would you perhaps know how to solve the problem of my latest edit above.
Would be great to borrow your expertise again  :-)

Comment: @HenriBranken, It appears that `longtable` ruins the internal LaTeX parameter `\@colroom`, which `multicols` needs to break the text into columns. So save `\@colroom` before the `longtable` and restore it after. See my update.
Don't forget to delete `general.ist` before running this otherwise you will still use the old version.

Comment: **@Pieter van Oostrum**, thank you for your insights.  However, I'm not getting the expected output.  If you're keen on the following idea, you may `clone` [this GitHub link](https://github.com/HenriBranken/Tuttle__Learning_Japanese_Kanji/tree/master/tuttle_kanji) and work with the tuttle.tex file...  Please give met your **_GitHub profile name_** so that I may add you as a collaborator.