# Distribute very long table to multicolumns

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multicol, pgfplotstable

I have a table with 102 rows (102 = 17 x 6). 
How can I put that into a multicolumn-environment with 6 columns which have 17 rows each? 
With other words: How can I enforce a column break after each 17th row?

Hint: The table content itself should **not be splitted**, because there is much higlighting-stuff later (with pgfplotstable). 
Hint: The table-rows have a content like in the picture.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article} 
 \usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
%\usepackage{longtable}% Does not work in multicol
\usepackage{supertabular}% Does work in multicol

\begin{document} 
% Create an example table ====================
\def\OutFilename{\jobname-meta.txt}
\newwrite\MyFile
\immediate\openout\MyFile=\OutFilename

\foreach \n in {1,...,102}{%%
\immediate\write\MyFile{(\n), AAA, BBB }
}%%
\immediate\closeout\MyFile
%Test: \input{\OutFilename}
%===================================

\begin{multicols}{6}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, col sep=comma,
column type={}, % seems to be needed 1/2 
begin table={\begin{supertabular}{ l l l }},% column types defined here 2/2
end table=\end{supertabular},
% Does not work:
%every nth row={17}{after row={\vfill\null\columnbreak} },
%every row no 3/.style={before row=\vfill\null \columnbreak}},
]{\OutFilename}
\end{multicols}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594580/113546) for integrating a `longtable` inside `multicols`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article} 
 \usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}% Does not work in multicol
%\usepackage{supertabular}% Does work in multicol
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newlength\mysavecolroom

\begin{document} 
% Create an example table ====================
\def\OutFilename{\jobname-meta.txt}
\newwrite\MyFile
\immediate\openout\MyFile=\OutFilename

\foreach \n in {1,...,102}{%%
\immediate\write\MyFile{(\n), AAA, BBB }
}%%
\immediate\closeout\MyFile
%Test: \input{\OutFilename}
%===================================

\begin{multicols}{6}
\makeatletter\mysavecolroom=\@colroom\makeatother
\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox{
\makeatletter\col@number\@ne\makeatother
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, col sep=comma,
column type={}, % seems to be needed 1/2 
begin table={\begin{longtable}{ l l l }},% column types defined here 2/2
end table=\end{longtable},
% Does not work:
every nth row={8}{before row={\rowcolor{yellow}} },
]{\OutFilename}
\unskip
\unpenalty
\unpenalty}
\makeatletter\@colroom=\mysavecolroom\makeatother
\unvbox\ltmcbox
\end{multicols}  
\end{document}
```

I have added some highlighting to show that that works.
No `\columnbreak`s are necessary, as `multicols` does the balancing itself.

[image]

Comment: This is a very professional solution that is amazingly simple if one knows the commands. Helps me good!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a tabular but output the data simply in boxes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
%

\begin{document}
% Create an example table ====================
\def\OutFilename{\jobname-meta.txt}
\newwrite\MyFile
\immediate\openout\MyFile=\OutFilename

\foreach \n in {1,...,102}{%%
\immediate\write\MyFile{(\n), AAA, BBB }
}%%
\immediate\closeout\MyFile
%Test: \input{\OutFilename}
%===================================

\makeatletter
\begin{multicols}{6}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, col sep=comma,
header=false,
every head row/.style={output empty row},
column type={}, % seems to be needed 1/2
begin table={},% column types defined here 2/2
end table={},
every nth row={17[-2]}{after row={\columnbreak} },
every nth row={102[-2]}{after row={}},
/pgfplots/table/typeset cell/.code={%
\ifnum\c@pgfplotstable@colindex=\c@pgfplotstable@numcols\relax
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{#1\\}%
\else
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noindent\makebox[3em][l]{#1}\quad}%
\fi
}
]{\OutFilename}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, ok. I think that will work.  
And that the multicols became larger than the content is a multicol.sty "feature", I guess?

Comment: Seems that this method kills other keys. I can't use `%\usepackage{colotbl}         every row no 5/.style={   before row=\rowcolor{yellow}},`

Comment: well sure you no longer have a tabular. Use simply \color{yellow}. Or \colorbox or whatever.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand: this creates a table-look-like. Puh, but that's not so good. I fera, I can't use that solution.

Comment: why not? you can do everything you can do with a table also without a table and with much less interference to multicol.

Comment: The first problem is that the method ruins the look of the document since the multicols span the whole page, not just the filled area.

Otherwise I can't use practically anything from pgfplotstable (e.g. skip rows etc.)

Comment: the multicol behaviour is quite unrelated as you could easily check by creating a simple multicol.

Comment: This is certainly a true statement and the method may be technically correct somewhere, but the solution is practically inapplicable.

Comment: the problem with multicol is that there is a \newcolumn too much (at the end), so you will have to tell somehow pgfplotstable not to insert it at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\SetTblrTemplate{head,foot}{empty}

\begin{document} 

\def\OutFilename{\jobname-meta.txt}
\newwrite\MyFile
\immediate\openout\MyFile=\OutFilename
\foreach \n in {1,...,102}{%
  \immediate\write\MyFile{(\n), AAA, BBB}%
}%
\immediate\closeout\MyFile

\begin{multicols}{6}
\let\newpage=\par
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  col sep = comma,
  skip coltypes,
  begin table={\begin{longtblr}[
    halign = l,
    headsep = 0pt,
    footsep = 0pt,
    presep = 0pt,
    postsep = 0pt,
  ]{
    colspec = lll,
  }},
  end table = \end{longtblr},
  header = false,
  every head row/.style = {output empty row},
  every nth row = {17}{before row=\pagebreak},
  every nth row = {7}{before row=\SetRow{yellow7}},
]{\OutFilename}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not realize in the documentation that tabularray articulate itself super well with pgfplottable!!

Comment: @Jet In fact, `pgfplotstable` is flexible and works well with other table packages. Anyway, It would be better to add more contents in this topic to `tabularray` documentation.